# How to get selected columns from the database using $wpdb->get_results();

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm looking for a solution in $wpdb->get_results() which is equivalent `PDO::FETCH_NUM`.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
function get_data( $token, $field ){
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->show_errors();
        $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT '.$field.' FROM ' . $this->get_table(). '  WHERE  token =\''.$token.'\' ORDER BY id DESC');

        return $result[0];

    }
```

As you can see from my query above, I'm selecting specific columns from the database, but I don't know how to access selected column using $wpdb->get_results();

I would like to get the value of the `$field` column based on the where clause criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deep research I have gotten a solution.

Basically, this is how to get the `$field` column.

```
function get_data( $token, $field ){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT '.$field.' FROM ' . $this->get_table(). '  WHERE  token =\''.$token.'\' ORDER BY id DESC');

    $data = ""; 

    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        $data = $value->$field;
    }

    return $data; 
}
```

To make it simple, let's assume you have a column called `first_name`, this is how to get the `first_name` column from the database.

```
function get_data( $token ){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT first_name FROM your_table_name WHERE  token =\''.$token.'\' ORDER BY id DESC');

    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        echo $data = $value->first_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can you get this without foreach loop. let's say one is selecting count(column) that one does not need loop, any direc way to get it?